# Check for already open browser and URL

Tags: vb.net, url, textbox

Is there a way to check for already open browser windows with specific URL's in VB.NET so that `Process.Start` does not open new browser windows? For example, if I already have Pinterest open, I want to send my new search to the already open window from my TextBox.

My code which opens new window every time:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "https://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=" & Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(TextBox1.Text))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet should do it for you.

It will browse through windows explorer's windows for internet explorer instances that contain your search query (Squery) and asks the user to enter a search query.

The used reference is found at (%Windir%\System32\shdocvw.dll)

```
Sub Main()
        Dim shellWins As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
        Dim explorer As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

        shellWins = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
        Dim SQuery As String = "https://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q="
        For Each explorer In shellWins
            If explorer.Application.Name = "Internet Explorer" And explorer.LocationURL.Contains(SQuery) Then
                explorer.Navigate(SQuery & InputBox("Pinterest", "", Nothing, Nothing))
            End If
        Next

        shellWins = Nothing
        explorer = Nothing
    End Sub
```

[image]